# How do I record a specific application running on my Mac using ffmpeg?

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg, macos-high-sierra

I just installed ffmpeg with using home-brew on Mac HighSierra.  I want to record the contents (video only is fine) of an application running on my machine (as opposed to my entire Desktop).  So I tried running the below

```
davea$ ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 25 -i title=DOSBox
ffmpeg version 3.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Unknown input format: 'gdigrab'
```

but as you can see, I'm getting this

```
Unknown input format: 'gdigrab'
```

error.  What's the right way to record video on my computer for only a specific application using ffmpeg?

**Edit:** Using hte suggestion in comments, I got this other error ...

```
davea$ ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i ""
ffmpeg version 3.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fcbc160d0c0] AVFoundation video devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fcbc160d0c0] [0] FaceTime HD Camera
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fcbc160d0c0] [1] Capture screen 0
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fcbc160d0c0] AVFoundation audio devices:
[AVFoundation input device @ 0x7fcbc160d0c0] [0] Built-in Microphone
: Input/output error
```

Comment: Did you read [this](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop)? Without much exp with this, your forced tool (*gdigrab*) looks windows-only to me.

Comment: are you talking about the "ffmpeg -f avfoundation -list_devices true -i """ included int aht link?  If so, I edited my question to include the erorr that results.

Comment: You only did half of the proposed steps there. Use the info obtained to start the real-capture.

Comment: What output in my question shoud I use?  Is the "Input/output error" taht I received normal?

Comment: The `Input/output error` is normal because your command was intended to only list available devices. Please read the article sascha provided and refer to the [avfoundation device documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#avfoundation).

Answer (score 1):

The avfoundation input device appears to only be able to capture the whole desktop, but you can use the crop filter to grab only a specific area of the desktop.

The output from your `-list_devices` command shows two video devices: a webcam and your desktop (named `[1] Capture screen 0`).

The following example will capture the desktop and ignore the audio device. Then the crop filter will make a 800x600 sized video from an area 24 pixels from the left and 180 pixels from the top:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "1:none" -vf "crop=800:600:24:180,format=yuv420p" output.mp4
```

The format filter was added for QuickTime compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Although you have mentioned `ffmpeg`, I just wanted to make you aware you can also achieve your stated aim of *"grabbing part of the screen"* without needing to install any additional software just using the tools that come ready-installed with macOS - namely **QuickTime** which Apple unfortunately call *"QuickTime player"* belying the fact that it can record as well as play.

So, to get started, do a *"Spotlight search"* for **QuickTime** by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> and starting to type "QuickTime". As soon as it guesses you mean "QuickTime", hit <kbd>Enter/Return</kbd>.

No go to the *"File"* menu and click *"New Screen Recording"*. Press the red "record" button" and it will let you drag out a rectangular area of what you want to record. When you are finished, the "Stop" button is up in the top-right corner of the screen near the clock.

Comment: To clarify -- I dont' want to captrue part of the screen, I want to capture the output from one application only.  Maybe taht's the same thing, but if I'm only capturing a certain sectin of the screen and anotehr application falls above the part of the screen I want to capture, now I'm capturing another app, which I don't want.

Comment: If that is the case, I think you're going to be disappointed with `ffmpeg` and `QuickTime` - they record the screen at a specific location, and it is not constrained to a single application. Maybe you could elaborate on what the application is - as some applications can be coaxed into producing a stream suitable for `ffmpeg`.